# Postgres Row Level Security in function. Problem with session variable set equals function's parameter

Tags: postgresql, row-level-security

I have added Row Level Security to  my test table. RLS is working correctly if I set session variable "my.user_id" = '1' inside of function. Unfoturnetly, if I am setting session variable equals some of function's parameter, RLS policy doesn't see it. Can someone tell, is it even possible to set variable for RLS equals function's parameter?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sbx.get_expenses_by_ppp_table_2(v_user_id character varying,day character varying)
 RETURNS TABLE(report_id integer, report_row_id character varying, report_row_name character varying, row_level_num integer, fact_amount numeric, plan_amount numeric, execution_percentage numeric, daily_fact_amount numeric)
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
  #variable_conflict use_column
   declare 
        report_day date;
        report_year int4;
    
    begin
    
    report_day := day::date;
    report_year := date_part('year', report_day);
   
    set "my.user_id" = v_user_id; 

    return query select 1 as report_id,
                        ex.ppp_code as report_row_id,
...............
........
...
```

I have tried many ways of set variable equals parameter, nothing is working as I want.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe , (set "my.user_id" = '1';) is working fine, but  (set "my.user_id" = v_user_id;) is not

Answer (score 0):

If you

```
SET my.user_id = v_user_id;
```

you set the placeholder parameter to the literal value `'v_user_id'`.

You can achieve what you want by calling the `set_config()` function:

```
PERFORM set_config('my.user_id', v_user_id, FALSE);
```

Comment: thank you very much for help! it is working.)